# interpreting scatter plots

Tags: r, scatterplot, poisson-regression

I have plotted my predictors versus my response variable in order to be able to fit a good Poisson model to my data. However i am getting  those scatter plots for nearly all predictors which make me rather worried since including these predictors is making my residual deviance a value of 575 on 571 df(high enough) Thanks  [image: scatterplot]

Comment: (1) did you have the variables "the wrong way around"? (2) With discrete variables only taking a few values, consider doing a table rather than a plot, to start with; (3) If you do do a plot, consider jittering both variables, rather than only one; (4) can you tell us something about the two variables? Why does 'ageveh' only take the values 0 and 1? (5) *Why are you worried*??

Comment: I have considered ageveh as a factor(taking 0  for new cars and 1 for old cars)i have replotted it taking jitter on both variables and obtained the edited plot. However i am worried since all my scatter plots of predictors versus response variable are similar resulting in that my Poisson model with my predictors is constantly giving me high residual deviance which is a sign of "not good fit" @ Glen_b

Comment: You seem to have the same plot twice ... but it's much more informative, at least. When you say you're getting 'high residual deviance' ... how high is high? What's the model? Note that now your concern isn't some feature of the plot, it's something else. Perhaps you should clarify your question and and some details.

Comment: the residual variance is about 650 with high AIC about 1500 @ Glen_b

Comment: How can the residual *variance* be 650? That makes no sense for the data you show. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Actually i included other predictors in my model and fit a Poisson regression model. However all my scatter plots of predicted versus response variable ressemble that i posted. I was just trying to know if my predictors are correct to include in my model (that is based on the linearity assumption) and whether thats could be causing the evetually high residual variance? @ Glen_b

Comment: All the data values shown are between 0 and 8. Therefore a model with only an intercept on that data will not have a residual standard deviation exceeding 4 (probably more like 2.5). Therefore, none of the fitted models can have a residual variance exceeding 16. I ask again, *did you mean something other than residual variance* for the value of 650? Perhaps residual deviance? What makes the value surprising? What was the d.f.? When I asked for more details, I meant you should put them in your question -- other readers shouldn't have to read the comments to figure out what you're worried about.

Comment: My sincere apology i wrongly written it, i actually meant the residual deviance 575 on 571 df. In my opinion it is high enough which makes me quite anxious. Thanks and once again my apology @ Glen_b

Comment: A residual deviance of 575 on 571 df is pretty much exactly what you'd expect if your model was correct! Why do you think it's large?

Comment: Actually i saw a pdf where it has been told that the residual deviance of 580 with df 12 was too large ( and hence not a good fit) but i supposed this was due to the relatively low df? so from what i have understood since my df is large so a large residual deviance is expected? So if my Poisson regression model is giving me a residual variance of 575 based on 571 df, so its not something to worry about?Thanks @ Glen_b

Comment: (You need to stop calling the residual deviation the residual variance. They're not the same.) If the model for the mean and variance in the GLM is suitable, the residual deviance should be approximately chi-square distributed, with the given residual degrees of freedom. The mean of a chi-square is its degrees of freedom. So with df=12, a deviance of 575 or more would be gigantic, an extremely unusual event. With df=571, you'd see something more extreme than that almost half the time.

Comment: You might find reading from about halfway down [this page](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2006spring/ecol/145/001/docs/lectures/lecture22.htm) helpful.

Comment: (sorry once again for the typing mistake) sincere thanks for helping me out :) @ Glen_b

Comment: I called it the wrong thing myself up there. I should have typed 'residual deviance'.