# Interpreting AIC and deviance values

Tags: poisson-regression, deviance

```
I have fitted a glm Poisson to my frequency data and obtained the result:
```

Null deviance: 657.49  on 583  degrees of freedom

Residual deviance: 575.00  on 571  degrees of freedom

AIC: 1534.4

Is the high AIC value and relatively high residual deviance a serious matter to be taken into consideration? Thanks

Comment: Thanks but still it is mentioned there the lower the better AIC that what i wanted to confirm here an also on the residual deviance which has not been discussed there @ Andy

Comment: What makes you assert that the AIC is high? I already explained to you [on a previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88083/interpreting-scatter-plots) that that residual deviance is *not* high. Do you think the answer will be different on different days?

Answer (score 2):

AIC is used in comparing models; a single AIC has, as far as I know, little utility.